# Log4j does not write nor creates new file

Tags: java, logging, plugins, log4j, log4j2

I have been trying to set up Log4j2 logger in my Spigot plugin. It does not create any logging file, however it logged the messages into console. To add, it didn't log tracing messages although I set whole logger to "trace". I tried then removing console appender and it still logged messages to console. It seems like Log4j is ignoring log4j2.xml. Thank you for any help!

My code:

```
package main.java.sk.trollyj;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

public final java.util.logging.Logger LOG;

public static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

public Main() {
    super();
    LOG = this.getLogger();
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    super.onDisable();
    LOGGER.trace("entry");
    LOGGER.error("DISABLE");

    LOG.info("Disabled!");
    LOGGER.trace("exit");
}

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    super.onEnable();
    LOGGER.trace("entry");
    LOGGER.error("ENABLED");
    

    LOG.info("Enabled!");
    LOGGER.trace("exit");
}
}
```

Logger LOG is Spigot's default logger which works with no problem.

log4j2.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">

<Appenders>
    <Routing name="file">
        <Routes pattern="$${sd:type}">
            <Route>
                <RollingFile name="Rolling-${sd:type}" fileName="${filename}"
                             filePattern="TribalWars/logs/-${sd:type}.%i.log.gz">
                    <PatternLayout>
                        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
                    </PatternLayout>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500" />
                </RollingFile>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Routing>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="main.java.sk.trollyj.Main" level="TRACE"/>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

[My classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZYIK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must you use log4j2 for logging? Bukkit has a built-in logger that works perfectly for most projects. I have used the Bukkit logger for all of my plugins, and rarely have I seen other plugins use it.
Bukkit's logger is as simple as running `Plugin#getLogger.info(msg)` - it also contains `warning` and `severe` (error) methods. No further setup required.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the RoutingAppender and using as a routing key the type field of structured data messages. The problem is, your example doesn't show you sending any structured data messages. If you aren't logging structured data messages using the Routing appender doesn't make a lot of sense.

Your configuration also shows you referencing ${filename} but that variable is never defined. So it is going to create a file named "${filename}" in whatever the current directory is when the application starts, if it has permission.

If it is logging to the console then it either didn't find your configuration or encountered an error with it. You should start your app with -Dlog4j2.debug=true to see what happens during logging configuration.